# After submitting jquery dialog box is not closing

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-dialog

I have a modal dialog which has a form. When a user clicks the submit button on the dialog, I want the form to be submitted, and it works fine. But problem is after submitting the form the dialog is not closing and after refreshing only data is added into the grid.
Here is my dialog box

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen : false,
                height : 400,
                width : 800,
                modal : true,
                title: "Currency Details",
                close : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            });
        });
```

Here is my ajaxSubmit

```
  function saveCurrencyAjax() {
        var str = $("#enumCurrency").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "../currency/saveEnumCurrency.action",
            data : str,
            success : function(response) {alert("success call");
                $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
                $('#currencyGrid').flexReload();
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    };
```

This is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping( value="/currency/saveEnumCurrency.action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveEnumCurrency(@ModelAttribute EnumCurrency enumCurrency, Errors errors) throws Exception {   

    ModelAndView mvc = null;
    try{
        List<EnumCurrency> enumCurrencys =  new ArrayList<EnumCurrency>();
        enumCurrencys.add(enumCurrency);
        List<EnumCurrency> enumCurrencyList =enumCurrencyService.create(enumCurrencys);
        mvc =   new ModelAndView("setup/enumCurrencyList");         
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mvc; 
}
```

My  jsp page is here....

```
<%@ include file="/common/taglibs.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Currency </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
    href="<c:url value='/styles/style.css'/>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
    href="<c:url value='/scripts/jquery/css/jquery.ui.all.css'/>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
    href="<c:url value='/scripts/jquery/css/flexigrid.css'/>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
    href="<c:url value='/scripts/jquery/css/flexigrid.pack.css'/>" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/scripts/script.js'/>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/scripts/jquery/flexigrid.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/scripts/jquery/flexigrid.pack.js'/>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/scripts/jquery/jquery-ui.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/scripts/jquery/jquery.ui.core.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/scripts/jquery/jquery.validate.js'/>"></script>
<script src="../scripts/setup/enumCurrencyList.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen : false,
            height : 400,
            width : 800,
            modal : true,
            title: "Currency Details",
            close : function() {alert("close....jsp");
            $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        });

    });



    function submitForm() {

        validation part is here........
};

function saveCurrencyAjax() {
    var str = $("#enumCurrency").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "../currency/saveEnumCurrency.action",
        data : str,
        success : function(response) {alert("success call");
            $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
            alert("after close.....jsp");
            $('#currencyGrid').flexReload();
            alert("gridcall");
        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
};


</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog-form" ></div>
    <fieldset>
        <div id="currencyGrid" />
    </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting the `alert("success call");` after you submit the form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not closing the Jquery Dialog On form Submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352338/not-closing-the-jquery-dialog-on-form-submission)

Comment: In fact almost an exact duplicate..

Comment: try: `close : function() {
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
                }` maybe `this` is something else than you expected

Comment: @Rob Schmuecker  Ya i am getting the success message but the flow is not comming to $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');

Comment: @ joel harkes... tried that 1 also but still not working. And after refreshing only data is added into the grid.

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors in your console?

Comment: NO, i am not getting any error message,did i something wrong in controller? @ Rob Schmuecker

Comment: If you're not getting any messages in your browsers javascript debug console then I don't think it can be anything to do with your controller.  Can you show us the whole HTML or at least some more?

Comment: @ Rob Schmuecker....I added my jsp page  above please give a look

Comment: I have ran into similar problem and if I recall correctly, I solved it like this (this goes in success event of ajax call): 
$('#dialog-form').dialog('open').dialog('close'); 
Try it.

Comment: @ ksalk.........I tried ...not working....